# Do the master of The Ryozanpaku Dojo resemble certain stereotypical descriptions?

Tags: historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

Do the master of The Ryozanpaku Dojo resemble certain stereotypical descriptions? If they do, which stereotypical appearance would this be?

Comment: You mean like "lecherous old man" personality stuff or stuff that has to do with martial arts?

Comment: personality stuff

Comment: This question is too broad, please reference the [help center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help) for help with making your question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off looking over [this TV Tropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/KenichiTheMightiestDisciple) as there's a lot of common stereotypes/tropes that these characters are tied to.

Kenichi is kind of a gag show on top of shounen fighting so it's so chock full of stereotypes that it's hard to list them all.

Answer (score 3):

Stereotypical might not be the correct word to describe the masters, however, they all do have  common personalities compared to the millions of fighting mangas out there. I think it would be better to explain it as no one master has a truly unique personality that doesn't exist in other series.

Here are some of their following cliche personalities:

Kensei Ma (Kung Fu) - Perverted, Passive
Apachai Hopachai (Muy Thai) - Brainless brawn, yet soft on the inside
Shio Sakaki (Karate) - Boastful, tough, brawler
Koetsuji Akisame (Judo) - Cool, calm, collected tactician
Shigure Kosaka (Weapons expert) - Quiet, deadly, mysterious
Hayato Furinji (Furinji style) - Superman

As you can see, their personalities are quite common in other characters from other series. There is nothing personality-wise that makes these characters one of a kind.

Extra side note: Contrary to how the manga describes Akisame's style as Jujutsu, realistically it is Judo. Sakaki's style is also technically Karate-do as opposed to Karate-jutsu.